# Count number of occurrences of elements with vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I'm currently learning C++ (properly) by going through the book Accelerated C++ by Andrew Koenig and Barbara Moo on my own, and doing all the exercises in each chapter.

Exercise 3-3: *Write a program to count how many times each distinct word appears in its input*. To me this exercise seemed extremely difficult, especially considering: 1. The examples and other exercises in that chapter were relatively simple and 2. You are only allowed to use vectors, so nothing advanced. (or maybe it's just me misjudging the difficulty)

I searched the web for hints and saw others having trouble with this exercise, but the solutions offered by people seemed unclear to me. Most people suggested to use organizing methods that are introduced later in the book, which kind of defeats the point of the exercise. Finally, I pieced together hints and bits of methods I found on different forums (including here) to come up with my own solution:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::cin;
using std::setprecision;
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::endl;
using std::streamsize;
using std::sort;
using std::vector;

int main()
{

// Ask for string input

cout << "Please write some text, followed by end-of-file: " << endl;

vector<string> word_input;
string word;

// input words into string vector word_input

    typedef vector<string>::size_type vecsize;


    while (cin >> word) 
    {
        word_input.push_back(word);                 
    }

// sort the vector in alphabetical order to be able to separate distinct words

    sort(word_input.begin(),word_input.end());

// create two vectors: one where each (string) element is a unique word, and one
// that stores the index at which a new distinc word appears

    vector<string> unique_words;
    vector<int> break_index;


    for (int i=0; i != word_input.size()-1; ++i)
    {
        if(word_input[i+1] != word_input[i])
            {
                unique_words.push_back(word_input[i]);
                break_index.push_back(i);
            }

    }

// add the last word in the series to the unique word string vector

    unique_words.push_back(word_input[word_input.size()-1]);

// create a vector that counts how many times each unique word occurs, preallocate
// with 1's with as many times a new word occurs in the series (plus 1 to count the first word)

    vector<int> word_count(1,break_index[0]+1);

// if a new word occurs, count how many times the previous word occured by subtracting the number of words so far

    for(int i=0; i != break_index.size()-1;++i)
        {
            word_count.push_back(break_index[i+1] - break_index[i]);
        }

// add the number of times the last word in the series occurs: total size of text - 1 (index starts at 0) - index at which the last word starts

    word_count.push_back(word_input.size()-1-break_index[break_index.size()-1]);


    // number of (distinct) words and their frequency output

    cout << "The number of words in this text is: " << word_input.size() << endl;

    cout << "Number of distinct words is: " << unique_words.size() << endl;

        // The frequency of each word in the text

        for(int i=0; i != unique_words.size(); ++i)
            cout << unique_words[i] << " occurs " << word_count[i] << " time(s)" << endl;



return 0;
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this using vectors? Can the code be made more efficient by combining any loops?

Comment: This would be better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code review site.  My opinion is that your indentation and use of spaces around operators is weirdly inconsistent.  You can consolidate some of your work by using std::unique from <algorithm> which removes consecutive nonunique elements between two iterators (which will remove duplicates from your word list)

Comment: well, only very quickly scanning over your code, you spent quite a bit logic for this. It should only be a container ( list/vector ), a loop iterating over all words and an `if ( std::find() )` on your current container, if it already contains the word ( if not, insert it whereever you wish ). The total wordcount can be easily retrieved via container.size() and mustn't be saved on its own ( not that it hurts alot, its just not necc )

Comment: The problem is `O(n)` hard, Where n the number of input words. Your solution is `O(nlogn)` so your solution is not optimal. You can achieve the optimal `O(n)` but this means doing the equivalent of what `std::map<string, int> uniqueWords` does.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me (when I was working through this problem) was to use three vectors: an `input_vector`, an `output_vector`, and a `count_vector`. Read the user input with a `while` using `std::cin` until an escape character is entered: use `input_vector.push_back(input_word)` to populate the `input_vector` with words. Use `std::sort` from `<algorithm>` to sort the vector, and create `output_vector` (with one value, the first word in `input_vector`) and `count_vector` (with one value, `1`).

Then, for each element in `input_vector` (starting from the second, not the first), check whether the current element is the same as the last element. If it is, add `1` to the current element in `count_vector`. Otherwise, add the current word in `input_vector` to `output_vector` using `push_back()`, and increase the size of `count_vector` by one element (whose value is `1`).

Answer (score 0):

If you imagine that someone is using your code to process the entire works of Shakespeare, you would be wasting a lot of space by storing EVERY word. If you instead hold a structure of "the word" and "count of the word", you would only have to store the word "the" once, even if it occurrs 100000 times in the text your program is being fed. That is if you even need to know that the word has occurred more than once - if all you need is a list of unique words, all you need is to see if you have already stored the word. [Storing them in sorted order would make it possible to use `binary_search` to find them, which would help the runtime if you do indeed run the 800K (not unique) words of Shakespeare through your code]

Comment: There is an artificial "vectors only" restriction.

Comment: So, as long as you need only "which words have I got", you can still use `find` on the vector to see if you have seen this word before or not. Rather than storing ALL words, then removing duplicates afterwards.

Comment: Yeah, but the efficiency of that is awful

Comment: If you ensure the list is ordered, then you can use binary_search, like I suggested, which should be efficient.

Comment: The efficiency of maintaining a sorted vector as you continue to add to it remains awful.

Comment: Sorting a vector of size n is O(n log n), building a sorted vector of size n by selective insertion is O(n^2).

Comment: Clearly, it depends on how many duplicate words you'd have. But ideally, you'd want to use something like `map<>` rather than vector for this purpose.